# Create a table from another table information in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe CLIENTS with: 
Hotel number
Nationality
Date of arrive
Date of departure
Something like:

```
Client   Nationality   Hotel   Dateofarrive   DateofDeparture
Cl1          es         h1      21/07/2019    24/07/2019
Cl2          es         h1      23/07/2019    24/07/2019
Cl3          es         h1      06/07/2019    10/07/2019
Cl4          es         h2      05/07/2019    06/07/2019
Cl5          fr         h3      01/07/2019    02/07/2019
Cl6          pt         h1      07/07/2019    09/07/2019
```

And i want a dataframe Hotel and for each hotel of the dataframe i want all the clients that are of spanish nationality and all the nights they have sleept in the hotel, the same for french nationality and portuguese. 
Something like:

```
Hotel    CliEspan  Nights  CliFrench Night CliPortug Night 
H1           3       8       0         0          1      2
H2           1       5       1         1          0      0
```

Comment: Give us a sample of the data using `dput` and copy/pasting the output here please

Comment: Sorry, why does hotel h2 have 5 nights? Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a data.table option using dcast to cast the data to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# convert to date and calculate nights
df[, Dateofarrive := as.Date(Dateofarrive, format = '%d/%m/%Y')]
df[, DateofDeparture := as.Date(DateofDeparture, format = '%d/%m/%Y')]
df[, nights := as.numeric(DateofDeparture - Dateofarrive)]

# dcast to wide format
new <- dcast(df, Hotel ~ Nationality, value.var = 'nights',
             fun.aggregate = list(sum, length))
names(new) <- gsub('nights_length', 'clients', names(new))

new
#    Hotel nights_sum_es nights_sum_fr nights_sum_pt clients_es clients_fr clients_pt
# 1:    h1             8             0             2          3          0          1
# 2:    h2             1             0             0          1          0          0
# 3:    h3             0             1             0          0          1          0
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. We convert `Dateofarrive` and `DateofDeparture` to actual Date object then calculate the difference in by subtracting two dates, `group_by` `Hotel` and `Nationality` and `sum` total number of days and total number of entries in each group. Convert to long format, combine columns and `spread` it to wide format by filling missing values to 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Dateofarrive, DateofDeparture), as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y") %>%
  mutate(days = as.integer(DateofDeparture - Dateofarrive)) %>%
  group_by(Hotel, Nationality) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(days), 
             n = n()) %>%
  gather(key, value, total, n) %>%
  unite(col, Nationality, key, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(col, value, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why we have 5 nights for hotel `h2` but another `dplyr` possibility(can then `spread`:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Client,Hotel,Nationality) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Date")),list(~lubridate::dmy(.))) %>% 
   summarise(Time = DateofDeparture- Dateofarrive) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(Hotel, Nationality) %>% 
   mutate(Nights= as.numeric(sum(Time))) %>% 
   tidyr::spread(Hotel, Nights, fill=0) %>% 
   rename_at(vars(contains("h")),list(~paste0(.,"_nights")))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Nationality [3]
  Client Nationality Time   h1_nights h2_nights h3_nights
  <chr>  <chr>       <drtn>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Cl1    es          3 days         8         0         0
2 Cl2    es          1 days         8         0         0
3 Cl3    es          4 days         8         0         0
4 Cl4    es          1 days         0         1         0
5 Cl5    fr          1 days         0         0         1
6 Cl6    pt          2 days         2         0         0
```